# Selecting the Ids of a table where 3 or more column are duplicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to select the ids of 3 columns that I have in my table that all contain the same data except for when the first occurrence of the duplicate was inserted. For example my table is as follows:

`Select * From Workers`

```
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
| id | name   |JobTitle| description  |    
+----+--------+--------+--------------+    
| 1  | john   |Plumber |Installs Pipes|    
| 2  | mike   | Doctor |Provides Meds |   
| 3  | john   |Plumber |Installs Pipes|    
| 4  | john   |Plumber |Installs Pipes|    
| 5  | mike   | Doctor |Provides Meds |    
| 6  | mike   | Doctor |Provides Meds |   
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
```

What im basically trying to get is the ids of all the duplicates records expect for the lowest or first id where a duplicate has occurred.

```
SELECT t1.id 
From workers t1, workers t2
Where t1.id > t2.Id and t1.name = t2.name and t1.jobTitle = t2.jobTitle and t1.description = t2.description;
```

The table i am working with had hundred of thousands of records and I have tried the statement above to get the ids i want but due to the size of the table I get the error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.userId' in 'where clause'

I have tried increasing the timeout in workbench but to no avail.
In this example I am basically trying to get all the ids except for 1 and 2. I thought the above query would have got me what i was looking for but this has not been the case and now I am not sure what else to try.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an 'INNER JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
From workers t1
INNER JOIN workers t2 ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.jobTitle = t2.jobTitle and t1.description = t2.description
Where t1.id > t2.Id ;
```

But i can't figure out how you got your message, there is no userid in sight

Comment: Apologies I copied the wrong error message by mistake. I get the error Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: All comparison cloumns should be in acomposite index to increase performance. If that is not enough you have to increase the timeouts on slow systems or big tables, also check the error log from the mysql server, the could be messages if some thing is a miss.

Answer (score 1):

The error message does not match your query (there is no `userId` column in the query) - and it is not related to the size of the table.

Regardless, I would filter with `exists`:

```
select w.*
from workers w
where exists (
    select 1
    from workers w1
    where
        w1.name = w.name
        and w1.jobTitle = w.jobTitle
        and w1.description = w.description
        and w1.id < w.id
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(name, jobTitle, description, id)`.